# When is the right time to set up iptables after system reboot?

Tags: iptables, reboot, cron

I have a shell script that sets up a packet filter using iptables. The script works fine, but since im using iptables, the configuration gets reset after a system reboot and the packet filter no longer applies.

My approach would be to simply call the script from a cronjob with @reboot, so it gets executed every time after the system reboots.

Is this safe? I'm not sure when exactly cron runs its reboot-cronjobs, is there a time slot between the actual system reboot and my firewall setup where the packet filter does not apply and my system is vulnerable?

(I'm aware that iptables is outdated. Switching to nftables is not an option.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I believe my question is clear: Is a cronjob fine for setting up a firewall? If no, when/how would you do it correctly